# PHP Form is not storing output in mysql data base

Tags: php

I have created a PHP Form in that if ID exists on the searched MRNumber then Form will be auto filled.If ID doesn't exists then user will fill the form.I am trying to submit the form and store in MySql database but form is not storing in database.

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');
    if(isset($_POST['mr_form']) && $_POST['mr_form']!=='' && isset($_POST['mr_number']) && $_POST['mr_number']!=='' ){
        if(isset($_POST['row_id']) && $_POST['row_id']!==''){
            $row_id = $_POST['row_id'];
            $sql_query = "UPDATE demographic SET 
            Financial_Category = $db->escape($Financial_Category),
            Age = $db->escape($Age),

            WHERE 1 AND MRNumber = '".$mr_number."' ";
            $res = $db->query($sql_query);
            if(!$res){
                //echo $db->error();exit();
                $_SESSION['_msg'] ='Data updateion failed! '.$db->error();
                $_SESSION['_msg_type'] ='success';//warning danger
            }else{
                $_SESSION['_msg'] ='Data updateion success';
                $_SESSION['_msg_type'] ='success';//warning danger
            }
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        }else{
            //for insertion

            $sql_query = "INSERT INTO demographic  MRNumber = '".$mr_number."' ";
            $res = $db->query($sql_query);
            if(!$res){
                //echo $db->error();exit();
                $_SESSION['_msg'] ='Data insertion failed! '.$db->error();
                $_SESSION['_msg_type'] ='success';//warning danger
            }else{
                $_SESSION['_msg'] ='Data Insertion success';
                $_SESSION['_msg_type'] ='success';//warning danger
            }
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't appear to define `$mr_number` anywhere, rather just check that `$_POST['mr_number']` is set.

Comment: Thank you for responding Obsidian.I will implement this method.

Comment: I have PHP form i am trying to store form output to multiple tables.It is storing data for single table but for remaining tables data is not loading.